# escape a + sign in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

How can I escape this?

```
/{\([^.{}]*)-}/
```

And this?

```
/{\([^.{}]*)+}/
```

Comment: What do you aim to get out of, or why must you, escape those?

Comment: salathe, I have found that + signs must be escaped when url encoding serialized session data.  So OP's question is a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the *parentheses*, the *braces* and the *plus sign* -- if you want to match them literally. The PHP code for your regex would then be:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\{\([^.{}]*\)-\}/', 'replace-string', $input);
```

...and...

```
$output = preg_replace('/\{\([^.{}]*\)\+\}/', 'replace-string', $input);
```

It will match things like `{(abc)-}` `{(abc)+}`.

Answer (score 1):

[preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote) will give you the answers.